# Using JPA2 criteria API without Metamodel on a List property

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

How can I formulate the following JPA2 criteria query without using the metamodel classes:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> emp = cq.from(Employee.class);
cq.where(cb.isEmpty(emp.get(Employee_.projects)));
cq.select(emp);
```

I would like to use:

```java
cq.where(cb.isEmpty(emp.get("projects")));
```

But I cant figure out how to convert the Path to an Expression, which is needed by cb.isEmpty...

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root emp = cq.from(Employee.class);
cq.where(cb.isEmpty(emp.<List<Project>>get("projects")));
cq.select(emp);
```

Or, using a `Path` variable:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root emp = cq.from(Employee.class);
Path<List<Project>> projects = emp.get("projects"));
cq.where(cb.isEmpty(projects);
cq.select(emp);
```

#### Reference

- `javax.persistence.criteria` API

  - [`<Y> Path<Y> Path.get(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html#get%28java.lang.String%29):